# How do I split array by memory limit?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, algorithm, memory-management

I want to split array of object into chunks with memory limit that is each chunk should not be greater than 4MB , is there any way to do it? With the below code I got the size of input array.

```
var sizeof = require('object-sizeof')

var arr = [{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"g1ob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"}];

console.log(sizeof(arr))
```

Comment: What data do you have in your array?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? There's a difference in how large the objects are in-memory within the Node process, or as e.g. JSON representations.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My array contains  Normal Objects with 100 fields in  each object

Comment: Actually I need to pass that chunked array to an API that has an payload limit of 4MB

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit to data, then you have to define your chunking algorithm to work within a *quota*. The steps are actually pretty simple:

1. Create a new chunk.
2. Add items to it until the quota is filled - do NOT exceed it.
3. If the quota is reached, start from 1.
4. If the end of the array is reached - finish.

Here is how an implementation can look like.

**NOTE**: I am trusting that the [object-sizeof](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-sizeof) library properly counts the size of objects. I'm not sure if object references actually need to be taken into account. So, *assuming the implementation is correct*.

**NOTE 2**: I couldn't find a CDN copy of the library, so I implemented a very dumb replacement algorithm for example purposes. Each key has a size of `1` and each value has a value of `1`. Objects values are recursively calculated.

```js
/*
 * dumb implementation of `sizeof` for example purposes.
 * The "size" is 1 for each key and 1 for each simple value.
 *  {a: "b"} has size = 2
 *  {a: {b: "c"}} has size = 3, etc.
 */
var sizeof = obj => Object.entries(obj)
  .reduce((sum, [key, value]) => 
    sum + 1 + (typeof value !== "object" ? 1 : sizeof(value)),
    0
  )

var arr = [{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"g1ob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"}];

function chunkToLimit(arr, limit) {
  var result = [];
  
  //variables needed for the loop. Initialised properly later
  var chunk;
  var remainingQuota = -Infinity;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var item = arr[i];
    var size = sizeof(item);

    if (size > remainingQuota) {
      //the current chunk that will be filled
      chunk = [];
      //account for the size of the empty chunk itself
      remainingQuota = limit - sizeof(chunk);
      
      //add to result
      result.push(chunk);
    }
    
    remainingQuota -= size
    chunk.push(item);
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log(chunkToLimit(arr, 10))
```

This will account for a *memory limit* but if you need to send this over the internet, then you'd be using a JSON serialisation and thus your payload may have completely different size than what a plain object would, since each item will be encoded to a string and moreover `{a: "b", c:"d"}` will not even be the size of `"a"` + `"b"` + `"c"` + `"d"` but will also include `{`, `}` denoting the object, `,` separating the properties as well as `"` surrounding each key and value. So, the size would look different from what an object would be.

Luckily, the size of a JSON is a lot easier to calculate. It's a string, so you just need to know the size of it. And to do that, you can use a [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) in Node.js. [`Buffer.byteLength`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_bytelength_string_encoding) can be used to directly calculate calculates the byte size of an object when serialised to JSON.

```
var sizeof = obj =>  Buffer.byteLength(JSON.stringify(obj), 'utf8')
```

In this case, you would need different steps than before:

1. Check if the chunk would exceed the limit if a new item is added.
2. If so, finalise the current chunk and start a new one.
3. Add the current item to the chunk.
4. Repeat until the array is exhausted.

Here is an implementation:

**NOTE**: I'm using a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) since it's available in the browser. The operation should be identical, only the `sizeof` function is changed.

```js
var sizeof = obj => new Blob([JSON.stringify(obj)], {type : 'application/json'}).size;

var arr = [{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"g1ob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"},{test:"gob", gg:"2"}];

function chunkToLimit(arr, limit) {
  //variables needed for the loop
  
  //start first chunk
  var chunk = [];
  //add it to the array
  var result = [chunk];
  var size;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var item = arr[i];
    //concat in order to not modify the chunk and do a check before actually adding
    size = sizeof(chunk.concat(item))

    //check if the limit would be exceeded
    if (size > limit) {
      //if so, start a new chunk
      
      chunk = [];
      result.push(chunk);
    }
    
    //add item to chunk
    chunk.push(item);
  }
  
  return result;
}

var result = chunkToLimit(arr, 60)

for (var chunk of result) {
  var prettyPrint = `${JSON.stringify(chunk)}
  size: ${sizeof(chunk)}`;
  
  console.log(prettyPrint);
}
```